# How to run an embed command in a command handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Okay, so for my command handler I have:

```
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is eating ${bot.guilds.size} shots of cum`)
    bot.user.setActivity("my girlfriend and her husband have sex", {type: "WATCHING"});
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {

        case "ping":
            bot.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
        break;

        case "myinfo":
                bot.commands.get('myinfo').execute(embed, args);
        break;
    }
```

The "ping" command works, but not the "myinfo" command.

My code for "MyInfo" is:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  description: "says ping!",
  execute(message, bot, args){
    message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle("User Info")
  .addField("Stupid name you got there", message.author.username)
  .addField("GOT YOUR ID FUCKER", message.author.id)
  .addField("Here's how long you've been on discord'", message.author.createdAt)
  .addField("And here's how long you been annoying", message.author.joinedAt)
  .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
  .setColor("RANDOM");

}




  }
```

The error I get is:

```
C:\Users\U\Desktop\Folders\Downloads, Setup, and Uninstall Files\Code\CharlesBot\index.js:33
                bot.commands.get('myinfo').execute(embed, args);
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\U\Desktop\Folders\Downloads, Setup, and Uninstall Files\Code\CharlesBot\index.js:33:43)
    at Client.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\U\Desktop\Folders\Downloads, Setup, and Uninstall Files\Code\CharlesBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\U\Desktop\Folders\Downloads, Setup, and Uninstall Files\Code\CharlesBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\U\Desktop\Folders\Downloads, Setup, and Uninstall Files\Code\CharlesBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\U\Desktop\Folders\Downloads, Setup, and Uninstall Files\Code\CharlesBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\U\Desktop\Folders\Downloads, Setup, and Uninstall Files\Code\CharlesBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\U\Desktop\Folders\Downloads, Setup, and Uninstall Files\Code\CharlesBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:210:5)
```

I'm doing this based off a tutorial, don't know too much about node.js. For tthe command handler he only showed how to do embeds, only normal text. I know it's probably simple but I've been working with it for a few hours.

Comment: Well you are only exporting one command... `ping`. How are you expecting it to find `myinfo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are those things in your myinfo command. I think you copy and paste the ping file in the myinfo file and changed the code but you need to change the name and the description of the command too.

```
module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  description: "says ping!",
```

You need to change them with your myinfo values to make it work. Like `name: "myinfo", description: "Displays my info"`

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. I should've probably just typed it out manually lol. Thank you <3

Comment: No problem  you can mark my answer as correct to "close" the thread